# Question regarding valid operation when proving subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

I want to show that if $H \subseteq G$ is a finite set, then $H \leq G$ if $H \neq \varnothing$ and $H$ is closed under the group operation from $G$.

The proof is straightforward, noting that since $H$ is finite $x,x^2,x^3,\dots$ must have terms that agree for different powers. So $x^a = x^b$ for $a>b$ wlog. The next step is to note that $x^{a-b} = 1$ and because $a-b > 0$ we must have $1 \in H$ as a power of $x$.

I think I'm just missing some obvious fact or not understanding the ambient group we're working in, but why can we go from $x^a= x^b$ to $x^ax^{-b} = 1$ when we don't already know that $H$ is closed under inverses? Is it that as elements of $G$ the inverse is does exist but we just don't know it's in $H$ yet? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: The equality $x^a=x^b$ holds in $G$, and it follows that $x^{a-b}$ is the identity element of $G$.

Comment: Ah of course, makes total sense phrased like that thanks! @Mark

Comment: You could write that as an answer, @Mark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that if $SS=S $ then $S$ is a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948151/show-that-if-ss-s-then-s-is-a-subgroup)

Comment: Mark's comment was what I was missing @AnneBauval.

Answer (score 1):

let $x,y\in H$.

in order to prove that $H$ is a subgroup we use:
theorem 1:
$H\leq G$ iff

i.) $H\neq \emptyset$.

ii.) $x\cdot y^{-1}\in H,\;\forall x,y \in $H$.

proof:
$H\leq G$, then.

a. $x\cdot y\in H,\forall x,y \in H$.

b. associativity is inherited from $G$.

c. $(\exists 1)| 1\cdot x=x \land x\cdot 1=x$.

d. $(\forall x\in H)(\exists x^{-1})| x\cdot x^{-1}=1 \land x^{-1}\cdot x=1$.

c. implies $H\neq \emptyset$ since $1\cdot 1=1$.

a. and d. imply
$x\cdot y^{-1} \in H$.

in the other direction,  assume i. and ii.
then:
from i. we have $\exists x\in H$.
hence from ii. we have $x\cdot x^{-1}=1\in H$.

$x\cdot y^{-1}\in H$ implies $y^{-1}\in H$.

Hence $x\cdot y\in H,\; \forall x,y \in H$.

So it is also true for $x$.
I.e. $y\cdot x^{-1}\in H$.
Thus every term has an inverse.
Associativity is again inherited from $G$.

$\square$.